CatapultR timing out when trying to fetch data
I'm trying to pull data from Catapult (GPS unit data) and using the package CatapultR. When I try and copy their demo to create a new object it gives me a timeout error
`stats_df <- ofCloudGetStatistics(
  token,
  params = c("athlete_name", 'date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'position_name',                  'total_distance', 'total_duration',
             'total_player_load', 'max_vel', 'hsr_efforts', 'period_id', 'period_name', 'activity_name'),
  groupby = c('athlete', 'period', 'activity'),
  filters = list(name = 'activity_id',
                 comparison = '=',
                 values = activities$id))`

and the error I get is

Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: [us.catapultsports.com] Operation timed out after 60003 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Is there a way to increase time without making alterations to package? This has 1500 activities over 8 years with a lot of data for each.
